# Why can I only call one action on a controller Blazor / aspnet core 3?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-web-api-routing, asp-net-core-spa-services

So I have two routes in a controller with 2 gets. When trying to call it from Razor only the first one is called. I'm not sure if I need to add something to the startup or an attribute.

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class TestController : BaseController
    {
             [HttpGet]        
            public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
            {
                     return Content("1");
            }        

            [Route("/callback")]
            [HttpGet("[controller]/[action]")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Callback(string state, string code)
            {
                         return Content("2");
            }
     }
```

In my startup I have the following endpoints configured

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();             
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
            });
```

I then use some script in my razor file code section to call the controller

```
 var httpClient = new HttpClient();
 httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(Navigation.BaseUri);
 var response  = await  httpClient.GetAsync($"Test/callback?code={Code}&state={State}");
```

However only the Index route can be called

Comment: Side note: you shouldn't  do `new HttpClient()`.

Comment: I am using blazor web assembly and it seems if I run it twice the httpclient is disposed.

Comment: Let it be injected - see the FetchData page.

Comment: Use either `[Route(...)]` or `[HttpGet(...)]` dont use both. e.g. [HttpGet("/Test/Callback")] is fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[Route("/callback")]
```

should be

```
[Route("/Test/callback")]
```

Comment: It needed a leading forward slash before the Test